# Is there a way to import stopwatch data into Numbers?

Tags: iphone, numbers

I use the stopwatch app to collect data sometimes, and often I'll have ~100 datapoints. (as an example, my light creaks periodically after I turn it off after leaving it on for a long time, so I timed that once to find out how the period of the creaking changes over time). After recently getting an iPhone 6s with iOS 9, I tried using the Numbers app to graph some results. However, typing in the ~100 results is a bit tedious, and I was wondering if there was a way to transfer the data from the stopwatch to Numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Down load BEST STOPWATCH and there is a copy option. This can then be transferred to an email or text. Then the data can be copied into a spread sheet.